# "I am filtering X" and "I have a X filter". Am I keeping X or discarding X?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, present-participles

I was writing some Java 8 Streams code. I have a list of files, but I want to keep all large files over 100 MiB.

```
// Filtering large files
details = details.stream()
        .filter(fileDetails -> fileDetails.getSize() > HUNDRED_MEBIBYTES)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `filter` Javadoc says:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.

Therefore I have to pass a predicate describing what I want to keep.

Writing that `// Filtering large files` comment gave me an uneasy feel, as I was hesitating on whether saying "Filtering X" meant keeping X or discarding X. I tried to think about it but then became confused (I've rewritten that comment `// Keep large files only` since).

Here's the heart of the question:

- If I am **filtering water** into a cup using a **water filter**, the cup will contain filtered **water**, and we discarded impurities.
- If I am **filtering air** entering into a room using a **air filter**, the room will contain filtered **air**, and we discarded dust.
- But if I am **filtering air** entering into my computer case using a **dust filter**, the computer will contain filtered air, and we discarded **dust**.

It seems that "filtering **X**" always mean "I **want X** and discard Y", but a "**Z** filter" would either mean "I **want Z** and discard Y" or "I want X and **discard Z**". Is it true? Is no one ever filtering impurities, or filtering dust?

Following that logic, I am always filtering large files (I would not say in this case I am filtering small files), but it is ambiguous whether I should have a "large files filter" or a "small files filter".

I have to admit, sometimes I don't remember whether the `filter` method is meant to have a predicate describing what I want to keep or what I want to discard, for example the following code does not do what one expects at first glance:

```
allMiddleNames = users.stream()
        .map(User::getMiddleName)
        .filter(String::isEmpty) // FIXME: This is wrong, should be "s -> !s.isEmpty()"
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

Is there a clear, deterministic use of the word filter, particularly when used with the following expressions?

- I am filtering X (`filtering` is a present participle)
- I have a X filter (`filter` is a noun)
- My container contains filtered X (`filtered` is an adjective)
- I have filtered X (`filtered` is at the past tense)

Comment: _Filtering X_ would not always connote "I want X." With no context, it would be more likely to connote the opposite, to this reader at least. There may be a standard usage in coding jargon, but idiomatically _filtering **out** X_ would always connote excluding X. _Filtering **for** X_ could connote including X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the definition below. I have selected three examples from the dictionary - the first is the neutral sense, the second has the filter-out sense, and the third has the filter-in sense.

> **Filter** *verb*
>   1 [with object] Pass (a liquid, gas, light, or sound) through a device to remove unwanted material.
>
> - *Fish sauce is what you get when you leave anchovies or similar small fish to pickle in brine until nearly dissolved, and then filter the resulting liquid.*
> - *We have been given a special machine for our living room which filters pure oxygen into his lungs.*
> - *the eye filters out ultraviolet radiation*
>
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/filter)

Technically, what you are filtering is the stream of things going **into** the filter. Using the term *filter* on its own is ambiguous in relation to whether things are removed or retained because both actions are intrinsic to filtering.

In your example, you are filtering the files, and *retaining* the large ones. Your comment can simply say `retain large files`.